# How to disable previous dates(in the enddate field) based on the date the user selected on the startdate field? (using input type "date" & javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have two input fields:

`<input type="date" id="start">`

and

`<input type="date" id="end">`

Is there a way I could disable the previous dates on the "end" input field based on the date the user has selected on the "start" input.

E.g: If the user selects "2022/01/11" on the start input field, it should automatically disable all previous dates on the end input field (user should only be allowed to select dates from 2022/01/11 or greater).

All this using javascript.

What I have tried:

```
$(function(){
    var dtToday = new Date();
    
    var month = dtToday.getMonth() + 1;
    var day = dtToday.getDate();
    var year = dtToday.getFullYear();
    if(month < 10)
        month = '0' + month.toString();
    if(day < 10)
        day = '0' + day.toString();
    
    var minDate= year + '-' + month + '-' + day;
    
    $('#txtDate').attr('min', minDate);
});
```

Which works but only for one input field.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could handle the "change" event of the start date input and update the `min` attribute of the end date input with the value of the start date input :

```js
$("#start").change(function(){
  $("#end").prop("min", $(this).val());
  $("#end").val(""); //clear end date input when start date changes
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="date" id="start" />
<input type="date" id="end" />
```

Comment: Thank you @Tom your answer solved the question and it works properly.